# Double-click throwing an error using d3.geo.zoom.js

Tags: javascript, events, d3.js

I'm using the [d3.geo.zoom.js library](https://gist.github.com/enjalot/31168147b88a1748bc8b/) and it's doing just what I want, except that it throws an error if somebody double-clicks, which then causes the globe to freeze up and stop responding to user input.  I re-downloaded the project and ran it unmodified and got the same error.

Here's my implementation: [codeasart.com/globe](http://codeasart.com/globe)

And the error, which you can easily replicate by double-clicking on it, is:

```
(index):108 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'preventDefault' of null
at SVGPathElement.<anonymous> ((index):108)
at SVGPathElement.t (d3.v3.min.js:1)
at SVGPathElement.<anonymous> (d3.geo.zoom.js:29)
at SVGPathElement.t (d3.v3.min.js:1)
at d3.v3.min.js:1
at c (d3.v3.min.js:3)
at SVGPathElement.<anonymous> (d3.v3.min.js:3)
at a (d3.v3.min.js:3)
at Object.c (d3.v3.min.js:3)
at Rn (d3.v3.min.js:1)
```

The first line shown in the error, index:108, is this:

```
d3.event.sourceEvent.preventDefault();
```

I tried putting that into a try/catch block, but that didn't solve it.

The only other line not in d3 itself is d3.geo.zoom.js:29, which is:

```
event.zoom.apply(this, arguments);
```

I tried that with a try/catch block as well.  No luck.

I just don't understand enough of the javascript/d3 event model to debug this.  Any help?

Answer (score 0):

I kept whacking away at this (checking every few minutes to see if anybody replied) and eventually determined that on line 18 of d3.geo.zoom.js:

```
point = position(projection, mouse0);
```

point was False (instead of being an array of two doubles) on a double click.

I just added a line:

```
if( !point ) return;
```

And that seems to have fixed things.

I'm would assume that it's simply a problem that the math breaks when the start and end points are the same, except that if I click very slowly without using the mouse it doesn't cause the error.  Only an actual double-click.